# Word used to refer to a large group when defining a smaller one?

Tags: single-word-requests

I’m trying to remember an uncommon word. It defines an exaggeration of language to include a large group of people when speaking about a smaller group. Like “*All of Chicago turned out for the game last night*”.

I thought it started with an O… I just can’t remember.

Comment: Is it synecdoche?

Comment: I don't know if this word is specific enough, but that statement qualifies as **hyperbole**: "exaggerated statements or claims not meant to be taken literally."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the opposite of synecdoche?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/144314/what-is-the-opposite-of-synecdoche)

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for '*overstatement*':

> **Overstatement**
>
> : the act of describing or explaining something in a way that makes it seem more important or more serious than it really is;
> exaggerate

(Cambridge)

---

'*Synecdoche*' doesn't start with an *O*, but it seems to be the best fit for your given example.

> Synecdoche is a type of figurative language that uses one part to refer to the whole, or the whole to refer to the part.

In your case, a whole is being referred to a part.