# What is this rhetorical device called (i.e. saying "the journal" while instead referring to an article inside the journal)?

Tags: rhetorical-devices

In a [question on a different SE site](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/202010/writing-the-introduction-section-of-an-academic-journal) the title is as follows

> Writing the introduction section of an academic journal

while the question is about writing the introduction section of a paper that will be published in an academic journal.

What is this rhetorical device (i.e. saying "the journal" while instead referring to an article inside the journal) called in English?

Comment: [Synecdoche?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/144314/191178)

Comment: '3000 sail' for '3000 ships' is synecdoche.  But 'The sails of 3000 ships' is merely a 'Norman/analytic genitive'. The introduction to/of the paper to be published in a journal' is non-figurative (unless you see 'paper' as a metonym, the base meaning being the substance).

Comment: I think this indeed is a synechdoche, but in my opinion, it's a very clumsy and rather pointless one. Just say "academic paper" rather than "academic journal".

Comment: It's only 'rhetoric' when it works. This phrasing doesn't work. An "introduction section of an academic journal" does not evoke any sense of a reference to a paper within the journal. It's like saying "the front door of the building" when wanting to reference the door to your own room.

Comment: Isn't this just an error? What was meant was an introduction to an article, but what was said was an introduction to the entire journal, right? The author of the sentence didn't intend for 'journal' to be understood as 'article', they just used the wrong word, right?

Comment: In the context of, e.g., selling things, this "rethorical device" may be labeled as fraud :)

Answer (score 4):

> What is this rhetorical figure in English called (i.e. saying "the journal" while instead referring to an article inside the journal)?

It is not a rhetorical figure - it is simply poor (or, to be generous, informal) English.

It should be

Writing the introduction section *for an article in* an academic journal.

I note that the OP has not given much context.

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of *metonymy*, in particular ***totum pro parte*** (the whole for a part) (Wikipedia, "[Totum pro parte](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totum_pro_parte)").

*Totum pro parte* often occurs with geography. For instance, when people say *Korea* (the whole) to refer to *South Korea* (one part of the peninsula), that is *totum pro parte*. It is technically incorrect but it's recognizable: a British friend who says, "Yes, I've been to Korea" is most likely talking about South Korea. In American college athletics, I could say, "Georgia is playing Kentucky on October 7th," and people would know I was referring to a part (university sports teams that go by the shortened names) and not the whole state of Georgia or Kentucky.

A rhetorical figure can be poorly used as well as well used. In this case, the writer has referred to what they're writing as *an academic journal*. The audience is confused because that whole (the journal) is not usually substituted for the part (the article). In this case, calling the error as *totum pro parte* (the whole for a part) is useful for describing what happened.